# How to create deb with custom layout

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a Play server application.

Currently, I have 20-line bash script that creates this deb:

```
/srv
  /foo
    /conf
      <unmanaged resources>
    /staged
      <jars>
```

I'd like to use sbt native packager to generate this.

Currently, `sbt debian:package-bin` gives me

```
etc/
  default/
    foo
  foo
  init/
    foo.conf
usr/
  bin/
    foo
  share/
    foo/
      bin/
        foo
      conf/
        <unmanaged resources>
      lib/
        <jars>
      share/
        doc/
          api/
            <docs>
      logs
      README
var/
  log/
    foo/
```

How do I do I get my desired layout? Do I need to implement an [archetype](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/tree/v1.0.0-M4/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes)?

I'm using SBT 0.13.7 and SBT native packager 1.0.0-M1.

Answer (score 2):

If your layout is close to the one already generated, you could use settings like `defaultLinuxInstallLocation` and `defaultLinuxConfigLocation`.

Or modify `linuxPackageSymlinks` and `linuxPackageMappings` directly, something like

```
    linuxPackageSymlinks := Seq(),
    linuxPackageMappings := {
      val libPath = "/srv/foo/staged"
      val libs = scriptClasspathOrdering.value.map { case (file, classpath) =>
        file -> classpath.replaceFirst("^lib", Matcher.quoteReplacement(libPath))
      }
      Seq(LinuxPackageMapping(libs))
      // plus configuration
    },
```

---

If you have lots of binaries to archive (i.e. you have lots of dependencies), `debian:packageBin` is pretty slow. For debugging, consider using `debianExplodedPackage`.

Also, know that whatever is in the directory `debianExplodedPackage` will get included in the archive, so if there's extra stuff in the .deb at the end, you may need to delete that directory.